# Why can't solve this equation, why there is no answer

Tags: equation-solving

Why can't solve this equation, why there is no answer.
Please give me advice if you can understand,

```
m=Subscript[p, 0, 8], Subscript[p, 1, 7], Subscript[p, 1, 8], \
  Subscript[p, 2, 6], Subscript[p, 2, 7], Subscript[p, 3, 5], \
  Subscript[p, 3, 6], Subscript[p, 4, 4], Subscript[p, 4, 5], \
  Subscript[p, 5, 3], Subscript[p, 5, 4], Subscript[p, 6, 2], \
  Subscript[p, 6, 3], Subscript[p, 7, 1], Subscript[p, 7, 2], \
  Subscript[p, 8, 0], Subscript[p, 8, 1], Subscript[p, 8, 2], \
  Subscript[p, 9, 0], Subscript[p, 9, 1], Subscript[p, 10, 0] 


soll=20 Subscript[p, 0, 8]==30 Subscript[p, 1, 7] + 30 Subscript[p, 1, 8], 
50 Subscript[p, 1, 7] ==50 Subscript[p, 1, 8] + 30 Subscript[p, 2, 6] + 
30 Subscript[p, 2, 7], 100 Subscript[p, 1, 8] == 20 Subscript[p, 0, 8] + 
30 Subscript[p, 2, 8], 50 Subscript[p, 2, 6] == 50 Subscript[p, 2, 7] + 
30 Subscript[p, 3, 5] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 6], 100 Subscript[p, 2, 7] == 
20 Subscript[p, 1, 7] + 50 Subscript[p, 2, 8] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 7], 
50 Subscript[p, 3, 5] == 50 Subscript[p, 3, 6] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 4] + 
30 Subscript[p, 4, 5], 100 Subscript[p, 3, 6] == 20 Subscript[p, 2, 6] + 
50 Subscript[p, 3, 7] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 6], 50 Subscript[p, 4, 4] == 
50 Subscript[p, 4, 5] + 30 Subscript[p, 5, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 5, 4], 
100 Subscript[p, 4, 5] == 20 Subscript[p, 3, 5] + 50 Subscript[p, 4, 6] + 
30 Subscript[p, 5, 5],50 Subscript[p, 5, 3] == 50 Subscript[p, 5, 4] + 
30 Subscript[p, 6, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 6, 3], 100 Subscript[p, 5, 4] == 
20 Subscript[p, 4, 4] + 50 Subscript[p, 5, 5] + 30 Subscript[p, 6, 4], 
50 Subscript[p, 6, 2] == 50 Subscript[p, 6, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 7, 1] + 
30 Subscript[p, 7, 2], 100 Subscript[p, 6, 3] == 20 Subscript[p, 5, 3] + 
50 Subscript[p, 7, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 8, 0] + 30 Subscript[p, 8, 1], 
100 Subscript[p, 7, 2] == 20 Subscript[p, 6, 2] + 50 Subscript[p, 7, 3] + 
30 Subscript[p, 8, 2], 50 Subscript[p, 8, 0] == 50 Subscript[p, 8, 1] + 
30 Subscript[p, 9, 0], 100 Subscript[p, 8, 1] == 20 Subscript[p, 7, 1] + 
50 Subscript[p, 8, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 9, 1], 80 Subscript[p, 8, 2] == 
20 Subscript[p, 7, 2], 50 Subscript[p, 9, 0] == 20 Subscript[p, 8, 0] + 
50 Subscript[p, 9, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 10, 0], 80 Subscript[p, 9, 1] == 
20 Subscript[p, 8, 1], 30 Subscript[p, 10, 0] == 20 Subscript[p, 9, 0], 
Subscript[p, 0, 8] + Subscript[p, 1, 7] + Subscript[p, 1, 8] + 
Subscript[p, 2, 6] + Subscript[p, 2, 7] + Subscript[p, 3, 5] + 
Subscript[p, 3, 6] + Subscript[p, 4, 4] + Subscript[p, 4, 5] + 
Subscript[p, 5, 3] + Subscript[p, 5, 4] + Subscript[p, 6, 2] + 
Subscript[p, 6, 3] + Subscript[p, 7, 1] + Subscript[p, 7, 2] + 
Subscript[p, 8, 0] + Subscript[p, 8, 1] + Subscript[p, 8, 2] + 
Subscript[p, 9, 0] + Subscript[p, 9, 1] + Subscript[p, 10, 0] == 1
```

It is difficult to see it because the code is long, however please advise why the answer doesn't come.
Is it because there is no linear independence?

Comment: You need to use something like `Solve` to solve equations.

Comment: Please take a look at some other examples (here on this site and in the documentation of Mathematica). Your code contains syntax errors and it's unclear to me what exactly you're after. Also, do not to use `Subscript` type variables unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Chris K   Thank you for advice.It solved properly.

Comment: @Lukas Lang  Thank you for advice.It solved properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extended comment.

Can we assume that `m` is a list of unknowns and that `soll` is a list of equations? If so you should put curly brackets `{ }` around them to indicate that they are a list.

I have put in the brackets and looked at your list of unknowns and list of equations. Just looking at the `Length` indicated that they are both equal to 21. Then I did

```
Solve[soll, m]
```

which gave me a list of solutions. However the solutions were in terms of the variables so there is a problem.

Next I changed your equations into a list of expressions by doing

```
e = soll /. a_ == b_ :> a - b
```

which gave a list of expressions. Next I looked at the variables in your expressions

```
v = Union[Variables[e]]
```

This gave me a list of your variables in the expressions. I then looked at its length

```
Length@v
```

> 27

so there are 27 variables in your expression and only 21 unknowns in your list `m`.

Which are your extra variables?

```
Complement[v, m]
```

> {Subscript[p, 2, 8], Subscript[p, 3, 7], Subscript[p, 4, 6], \
>   Subscript[p, 5, 5], Subscript[p, 6, 4], Subscript[p, 7, 3]}

As stated by @LucasLang it is best not to use Subscript. The simpler form is to use single brackets so p[0,8] is the simple Mathematica approach. Note the difference with double brackets `[[1,2]]` which means `Part`.

To get rid of your `Subscript` I did

```
m1 = m /. Subscript[p, a_, b_] -> p[a, b]
```

> {p[0, 8], p[1, 7], p[1, 8], p[2, 6], p[2, 7], p[3, 5], p[3, 6], 
>    p[4, 4], p[4, 5], p[5, 3], p[5, 4], p[6, 2], p[6, 3], p[7, 1], 
>    p[7, 2], p[8, 0], p[8, 1], p[8, 2], p[9, 0], p[9, 1], p[10, 0]}

and the same for

```
eqns = soll /. Subscript[p, a_, b_] -> p[a, b];
```

and now we can solve.

```
sol = NSolve[eqns, m1];
```

An example of the first of the solutions is

```
sol[[1, 1]]
```

> p[0, 8] -> 
>    0.194055 + 5.48157 p[2, 8] + 4.01839 p[3, 7] + 2.78865 p[4, 6] + 
>     1.76732 p[5, 5] + 0.529744 p[6, 4] + 0.226656 p[7, 3]

Which shows that the solution can only be obtained in terms of some of your variables.

Hope that helps.